# How to unmask a user in SQL server 2016?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL server 2016, masked data is hidden from most users, and only users with UNMASK permission can see the complete data. How can I do this?

Comment: Here is a great article on the topic. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Dynamic+Data+Masking/138553/

Answer (score 3):

> Dynamic data masking limits (DDM) sensitive data exposure by masking
>   it to non-privileged users. It can be used to greatly simplify the
>   design and coding of security in your application.

If you want to unmask UserA then,

```
GRANT UNMASK TO UserA
```

Answer (score 2):

GRANT UNMASK TO TheirUserName?